# How to make CSS style final?

Tags: html, css, dom

I need help on how to make CSS styles **final** so that they could not be overwritten by Javascript.

Problem: Sometimes, because of the **img** tag in the JavaScript code, everything, (all styles of ***all*** of the images) gets **overwritten**.

Here is my code:

```
 <img src='logoImg' style='width:45px; height:30px;' >
```

Please tell me ways to do this in JavaScript or in CSS itself.

Desired output: I need the Logo Image to have *final styling*. So it is not affected by JavaScript through the DOM (document object model).

Comment: This is a incorrect syntax, it should be `<img src='logoUrl' style='width:45px; height:30px;' >`

Comment: if you want to prevent JS from overwriting styles, you have to raise the styles specificity weight by using `!important;`

Comment: JavaScript will always have the potential to overwrite your CSS. What problem are you trying to prevent? The CSS and JavaScript in your site should be checked, and verified, before it's moved to production. If the user runs JavaScript client side, and then changes the appearance of the site, what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica that a very broad statement. JS will apply the stylign as `inline-style` and as such it will have a higher specificty weight then CSS by default. However it still is overruled by the specificty weight of `!important`.

Comment: Please, please, please... avoid `!important` at all costs!

Comment: @ChloeAnderson there is no other way then `!important` if he needs to overule `inline-style`. It exactly exist for such reasons. To raise the specificty weight to the maximum.

Comment: No, no, no, of course there's other ways! The bigger issue here is that his scripts are altering styles of which they shouldn't.

Comment: Fix the javascript, not the CSS

Comment: @tacoshy: you know that JavaScript can quite easily set new styles along with applying `!important` to those styles? [`setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue, priority)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)?

Comment: of course you can but thats not the question here. The question is, how to prevent that the applied inline-style overwrites existing CSS of specific images. And you cant set JS to give the inline-style a lwoer specificity weight then CSS.

Comment: The problem is there's no way to "finalise" CSS. Hence my question about what problem the OP it's trying to either solve our anticipate.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you want to prevent JS to overwrite the style of an image, you need to style it in CSS and add `important;` to raise it specificty weight. `!important` has a higher specificty weight then `inline-style` and as such JS style (JS add the style as inline-style) wont apply.

```js
function resize() {
  document.querySelector("img").style.height = "200px";
  document.querySelector("img").style.width = "200px";
}
```

```css
img.test {
  width: 45px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg' class="test">
<button onclick="resize()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding `!important` keyword to your CSS properties to prevent them from getting changed.

### Example

```js
const test = document.getElementById("test");

// The color won't change to orange
// due to !important keyword in the CSS code
test.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Ideally though it would be better to work around this using a different solution like using a more specific method of selecting an HTML element and changing it's properties.

If you have some kind of a style applied by selecting a `tag`, you can override it by using a `class` or an `id` when it comes to CSS. If you're searching for elements in JavaScript code, you can look for them by a `class` name or an id `value` instead.

An alternative solution in your case would be to re-write/modify the JavaScript code that targets your `img` tags and either skip images that have a specific class like let's say `logo`, or make a custom class for all your standard images that do not include your logo element and look them up in your JavaScript code using `document.getElementsByClassName` method.

Comment: `!important` should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Why should they be avoided?

Comment: Because it's basically terrible, and complicates future maintenance when future-you is trying to work out why they can't change this one setting.

Comment: @UTkY8oApLDOe92I check out the following article at MDN on ***!important*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Thank you for this answer!